# How can i add a lot of ENV variables to Elastic-beanstalk environments? with boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using boto3 to update environment variables but each update_environment() call forces the environment to fully "update" but i can't figure out how to do multiple values at once.

```
single_query = { 'Namespace': 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment', 
                        "OptionName": "{}", 
                        "Value":"{}}"}

stuff = [] 
for var in env_json.items():
    stuff.append(single_query.format(var[0], var[1]))
```

so env_json is a dictionary of the variables i want to add to the environment

This does not make a list as i wanted. How can i end up with a list of individual json objects that will be put into the OptionSettings parameter for update_environment() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, however, google linked me here while I was searching. In case anyone else stumbles upon this question while searching. Here's how I did it.

```
option_settings = []
for env_variable, env_value in env_variable_dict.items():
    opt = {
            'Namespace': 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment',
            'OptionName': env_variable,
            'Value': env_value
        }
    option_settings.append(opt)
response = client.update_environment(
    ApplicationName='appname',
    EnvironmentName='env-name',
    OptionSettings=option_settings
)
```